# Puppet - How to get all values in the same level of the hierarchy?

Tags: puppet

Let's say that I have the following data in the heira:

```
# web01.example.com.yaml
mykey: one
```

and

```
# web02.example.com.yaml
mykey: two
```

Both of them in the same level in the heira.
I want to get an array that merge all the values of specific key in the heira.
Is it possible?

Comment: You can do hash merges but not from every YAML file. Perhaps update to show your hiera.yaml and explain a bit more what your objective is?

Comment: I have the following hierarchy: common, site, service, customer. I have a service that needs to get all the configurations of the customers. These configurations appear in every customer. I want to deploy this configuration to the service so I need to merge all the customer configuration.